# Vue TypeError _vm is not a function

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

In my Vue component , called `Home.vue`, I am including [this Google Maps plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-google-maps), as follow

```
<GmapMap
 :center="{lat: 45.919849, lng: 25.0203875}"
 :zoom="7"
   map-type-id="terrain"
  style="width: 100%; height: 600px"
   >
<GmapMarker
:key="markerIdx"
v-for="(m, markerIdx) in results"
:position="getMarkerPosition(m.locationCoordinates)"
:clickable="true"
:draggable="false"
/>
</GmapMap>
```

The object `results` comes from a parent tag, and `m.locationCoordinates` is a `String`. The `:position` of `GmapMarker` needs a JSON Object. I am defining a `getMarkerPosition` function to transform that string into JSON, like so

```
export default {
      methods: {
   getMarkerPosition: function (coordinateString) {
          let split = coordinateString.split(',')
           return {
            lat: parseFloat(split[0]),
            lng: parseFloat(split[1])
            }
     }
  }
  }
```

but I'm ending up with a browser error saying

````
TypeError: _vm.getMarkerPosition is not a function
 at eval (eval at ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/template-compiler/index.js?            
 {"id":"data-v-8dc7cce2","hasScoped":false,"transformToRequire":{"video": 
  ["src","poster"],"source":"src","img":"src","image":"xlink:href"},"buble": 
 {"transforms":{}}}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js? 
 type=template&index=0!./src/components/Home.vue 
 (0.96557ac29cc33c9d2325.hot-update.js:22), <anonymous>:180:63)
  at Proxy.renderList (vue.esm.js?efeb:3705)
  at Proxy.render (eval at ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/template- 
  compiler/index.js?{"id":"data-v- 
  8dc7cce2","hasScoped":false,"transformToRequire":{"video": 

 ["src","poster"],"source":"src","img":"src","image":"xlink:href"},"buble": 
 {"transforms":{}}}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js? 
  type=template&index=0!./src/components/Home.vue 
 (0.96557ac29cc33c9d2325.hot-update.js:22), <anonymous>:173:47)
   at VueComponent.Vue._render (vue.esm.js?efeb:4544)
   at VueComponent.updateComponent (vue.esm.js?efeb:2788)
   at Watcher.get (vue.esm.js?efeb:3142)
   at Watcher.run (vue.esm.js?efeb:3219)
   at flushSchedulerQueue (vue.esm.js?efeb:2981)
   at Array.eval (vue.esm.js?efeb:1837)
   at flushCallbacks (vue.esm.js?efeb:1758)```
````

The entire code is in `Home.vue`. I only declare `Vue.use(VueGoogleMaps)` in `main.js`

Comment: What is your file structure and which file has the getMarkerPosition declaration?

Comment: @NickTucci Everything is in a single file, `Home.vue`. I only do a `Vue.use(VueGoogleMaps)` in `main.js`

Comment: try to replace `methods` by `computed` i think that `:position` accept a computed property

Comment: remove `:position="getMarkerPosition(m.locationCoordinates)"`, then add `<h1>{{getMarkerPosition}}</h1>`, what is rendered out?

Comment: If you hardcode the object, does it work?

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim Tried that before. Same error.

Comment: @Sphinx If I put `<p>{{getMarkerPosition("123,123")}}</p>` outside the `GmapMap` marker/tag, it renders correctly

Comment: @V.Sambor I'm not sure what that means in this context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I want to share my solution in case anyone runs into a similar issue.

The main problem was that my `GmapMap`'s parent was another component called `ais-results` (from [Vue InstantSearch](https://community.algolia.com/vue-instantsearch/components/results.html)) which had the `inline-template` attribute. That means whatever is inside the `ais-results` tag won't be able to see 'outside'.

My elegant solution was to extract the `GmapMap` in a separate component/file where I can define all my required methods. When I use my new component, I just pass data to it as `props`.

Another solution would be to avoid the `inline-template` attribute.

Related questions and resources:

1. [Vue: method is not a function within inline-template component tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51658044/vue-method-is-not-a-function-within-inline-template-component-tag)
2. [Vue inline template not finding methods or data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48189020/vue-inline-template-not-finding-methods-or-data)
3. https://medium.com/js-dojo/7-ways-to-define-a-component-template-in-vuejs-c04e0c72900d
4. https://community.algolia.com/vue-instantsearch/components/results.html

Keep in mind I'm a beginner in reactivity and Vue stuff. Cheers