# Vue inline template not triggering method even with emit

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4, nuxt.js

I'm wondering what I am doing wrong here, from what I can see this is the solution: [Vue: method is not a function within inline-template component tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51658044/vue-method-is-not-a-function-within-inline-template-component-tag?noredirect=1&lq=1)

However the method is still not triggering.

```
  <b-table
      :items="filtered"
      :fields="fields"
      sort-icon-left
      responsive="sm"
      @card-click="setUpdate"
    >
      <template v-slot:head()="data">
        <span class="text-info">{{ data.label.toUpperCase() }}</span>
        <button @click="$emit('card-click', data)">filter</button>
        <input
          v-show="data.field.showFilters"
          v-model="filters[data.field.key]"
          :placeholder="data.label"
        />
      </template>
    </b-table>

  methods: {
    setUpdate(field) {
      console.log("hello");
      console.log(field);
      this._originalField = Object.assign({}, field);
      field.showFilters = true;
    }
  }
```

Update

So the @click allowed me to to trigger the event but this lead to the table wouldn't update with the changed data with showFilters. Thanks to  MattBoothDev I found event-based-refreshing-of-data, however this oddly now prevents the data from changing. I.e. if field.showFilters is true it's true if I click the button.

```
 methods: {
    setUpdate(field) {
      this._originalField = Object.assign({}, field);
      field.showFilters = !field.showFilters;
      this.refreshTable();
      console.log(field.showFilters);
    },
    refreshTable() {
      this.$root.$emit("bv::refresh::table", "my-table");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using Bootstrap Vue?

What you're essentially doing here is putting a listener on the `<b-table>` tag for `card-click` but that event is essentially not happening within a *child* component of `<b-table>`.

Regardless, I'm not even sure you need the event.

`<button @click="$emit('card-click', data)">filter</button>`

can easily just be

`<button @click="setUpdate(data)">filter</button>`

EDIT:

It is good practice to use MVVM for Vue.js as well.

Rather than: `@click="$emit('card-click', data)"`

Should be: `@click="onFilterClicked"`

Then:

```
methods: {
  onFilterClicked (data) {
    this.$emit('an-event', data.some.property)
  }
}
```

This will make testing your code a lot easier.

Comment: Hi thanks! You're right I didn't need that, I get the console logs out so the function is being hit now but it doesn't seem to update the state, until the state is update with a different function like the sort click. Is is their an obvious reason this would not update the table?

Comment: @karl you could try https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table/#event-based-refreshing-of-data and call it in your setUpdate function

Comment: Ah thanks, thats useful, have updated my post with my implementation but still having some odd problems.